# How do you pass a dynamically built string as a http header in HTTP.call with meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm stuck having to use a legacy web service that takes a username and password and returns xml indicating if the credentials are valid. The legacy service requires me to pass an http header with the request that contains the user's password.  So, to get it to work, I had to hard code the password (actualUserPassword) in the header as follows:

```
  var urlToCall = "https://ourlegacyauthserver/auth?uid=" + username);
  var result = HTTP.call("GET", urlToCall, {headers:{"token:appname:127.0.0.1:actualUserPassword":""}});
```

This works when I hard code the proper password for the user on the server, but what I really need to do is build that header dynamically using the password variable, like this:

```
 var urlToCall = "https://ourlegacyauthserver/auth?uid=" + username);
 var headerString = "token:appname:127.0.0.1:" + password;
 var result = HTTP.call("GET", urlToCall, {headers: {headerString: ""}});
```

When I do this, the auth server does not see the header coming in.  What is wrong?  I'm just trying to replace the hard coded string: "token:appname:127.0.0.1:actualUserPassword" with a string variable I built using the actual password passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a javascript Object key problem. Try this instead:

```
var urlToCall = "https://ourlegacyauthserver/auth?uid=" + username);
var headerString = "token:appname:127.0.0.1:" + password;
var headerObject = {};
headerObject[headerString] = "";
var result = HTTP.call("GET", urlToCall, {headers: headerObject});
```

Comment: Thanks Larry, that worked!  Any pointers on things to read to understand this issue?

Comment: It's just basic JavaScript. When you want to programatically drive a key, you generally use the `myObject[myKey] = myValue syntax`. Only when your keys are defined in code can you use `myObject.myKey = myValue` syntax or `myObject = {myKey: myValue}` syntax.